# How to correctly use Steam API SetGameLauncherMode() function in an Unreal Engine Game?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, steamworks-api

I'm trying to get my game Steam Deck verified and to do that, I've been told that first time setup components "The Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime and Unreal Engine Prerequisites." need to have controller support.

Apparently this is done by using the "SetGameLauncherMode()" function in order to translate controller input into mouse input for this setup. I've tried using the code written below to do this, however I can't seem to get any controller support on these installers.

```
if (SteamAPI_Init())
{
    SteamUtils()->SetGameLauncherMode(true);
}
```

I've tried using this function on the Init() and InitializeStandalone() functions on my custom game instance class, which has had no success. I've also tried using a custom UGameEngine class and calling it in the Init() function of this, which also didn't work.
According to the Unreal Engine documentation, the game instance and game engine are the first two things created when playing the game, so I'm not sure how I could call the function any earlier in order for it to work on the first time setup components installers.

Has anyone had any experience with this, or knows how I could get this working? Thank you